# SQL count function difference between equals operator and in operator

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

This question is related to following hackerrank challenge:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/challenges/problem

The version that works returns the correct result set while the other returns an incomplete result set since count(*) does not work as expected with in clause

Only difference between the two code pieces is c_count instead of count(*) in the first clause of or.

Since c_count is equal to count(*), there should be no semantic difference. If `count(*) in` is wrong syntax, why does `count(*) =` work?

This works:

```
select count(*) as c_count ... having c_count in (select ...) or count(*) = (select ...);
```

This won't work:

```
select count(*) as c_count ... having count(*) in  (select ...) or count(*) = (select ...);
```

Here's the original queries. `/**/` comment calls out the difference between the two:

Working:

```
SELECT h.hacker_id
    ,h.name
    ,count(*) AS c_count
FROM Hackers h
JOIN Challenges c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
HAVING 
    /*USING c_count ALIAS*/ 
    c_count IN (
        SELECT hacker_c_counts2.c_count2
        FROM (
            SELECT count(*) AS c_count2
            FROM Challenges c2
            GROUP BY c2.hacker_id
            ) AS hacker_c_counts2
        GROUP BY hacker_c_counts2.c_count2
        HAVING count(*) = 1
        )
    OR count(*) = (
        SELECT max(hacker_c_counts.c_count1)
        FROM (
            SELECT count(*) AS c_count1
            FROM Challenges c1
            GROUP BY c1.hacker_id
            ) AS hacker_c_counts
        )
ORDER BY count(*) DESC,  h.hacker_id;
```

Not Working:

```
SELECT h.hacker_id
    ,h.name
    ,count(*) AS c_count
FROM Hackers h
JOIN Challenges c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
HAVING 
    /*USING count(*) directly*/ 
    count(*) IN (
        SELECT hacker_c_counts2.c_count2
        FROM (
            SELECT count(*) AS c_count2
            FROM Challenges c2
            GROUP BY c2.hacker_id
            ) AS hacker_c_counts2
        GROUP BY hacker_c_counts2.c_count2
        HAVING count(*) = 1
        )
    OR count(*) = (
        SELECT max(hacker_c_counts.c_count1)
        FROM (
            SELECT count(*) AS c_count1
            FROM Challenges c1
            GROUP BY c1.hacker_id
            ) AS hacker_c_counts
        )
ORDER BY count(*) DESC, h.hacker_id;
```

Comment: Remove as much code as possible, still having the problem.

Comment: I'm a bit baffled .  You have multiple queries and fragments, some of which work and some don't.  It is a bit hard to follow what you are asking.

Comment: could you check once more

Comment: I'm not able to replicate with a more simplified query [like this].(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/287e79/3) Perhaps I'm missing something though?

Comment: I've added your original complex SQL back in since there might be an issue besides the use of your alias vs the use of `count(*)` directly.

Comment: could it be related to MySQL version used in HackerRank?

Comment: It's clear that the first version works and the second one doesn't, but what does "Not working" mean here? Does it error? Do you get results that are different than you expect? You may need to share some sample data for us to dig in further.

Comment: the version which works passes the test in the website and returns the correct result set, other version does not pass the tests and returns an incomplete result set

Comment: Oh I see. So it could be something funky with their back end. I'm assuming it's a bit of a black box? I just tested that sqlfiddle version on 5.7.26 and it worked fine. Perhaps there is some buggy older version they use or some other secret sauce.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .....having h.c_count in..... Use the table Alias "h" before the c_count.

Good luck.

Comment: it already works with c_count in ...., what is weird is count(*) in ... returns an empty set

Comment: Did you try using the table alias before the .* ? If this has to do with mysql versions, could be this.

Comment: replacing ```count(*) IN``` with ```count(h.name)``` doesn't work either :(